# How to obtain a uniform sample from my SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-analysis

Say I have a simple table:

```
id, value
2, 5
4, 3
10, 4
20, 5
24, 4
40, 3
60, 3
80, 3
150, 3
90, 3
120, 3
```

As you can see the majority of the value column is 3. If I want to obtain a subset of this table, there is a high likelihood that 3 would dominate, i.e., `SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 10`. So how can I thus perform some statistics to ensure that I have a uniform distribution, i.e., a subset that contains 2 of each distinct value?

Comment: Which database do you use? Please add a tag, accordingly! Have you tried with a stored procedure, yet?

Comment: MS SQL. Sorry. Added

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 10` - this is not SQL Server syntax, are you sure about which RDBMS you are using...?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM data
)
SELECT
    id,
    value
FROM cte
WHERE rn < 3
GROUP BY value, id
```

It would give you at most 2 rows per value.

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b19a64f44a69a2179215e66ed5c0279)